# Lazily loading images in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, lazy-loading

Let us consider this code snippet

```
Image img=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("1.png");
g.drawImage(img,0,0,null);
```

What the code does is load the image `1.png` and draw it on a graphic context. Now what I observe is `drawImage`do not draw any image the first time it is called. Instead it draws the image on further calls. Now I think this behavior is due to asynchronous image load or the lazy behavior of the method.

To correct the problem what I could do is use the `javax.swing.ImageIcon` class like this.

```
Image img=new ImageIcon("1.png").getImage();
g.drawImage(img,0,0,null);
```

I want to know what are the other better ways to perform the same task.

Comment: 1) `g.drawImage(img,0,0,null);` should probably be `g.drawImage(img,0,0,this);` 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson The code is self sufficient.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I also think the code to be self sufficient. I do not understand your other requirements.

Comment: @AndrewThompson What he is saying is loud and clear.

Comment: May be the BufferedImage can help you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html

Comment: @BaLk *"What he is saying is loud and clear."*  Really?  Does `g` originate from a `JComponent` a `BufferedImage`or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends.

If you are loading the image over a "slow" connection (like the internet) or you are loading a sizable image, it's best to use a lazy loading approach.

This allows the application to continue running while the image is begin loaded.

Andrew is correct, you should be using `g.drawImage(img,0,0,this)`, as this allows the component to automatically update itself once the image has completed loading, without you needing to perform any other actions.

If you application relies on the image for some part of it's operation OR you are loading small images locally, it would be sufficent to use something like...

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageResource); 
// Where image resource is either a file or local URL (such as an embedded resource)
```

I personally, tend to use a background thread to load my images in most cases and use `ImageIO`.  In my `paint` method, I might use a small placeholder image if required to let the user know that I am loading the image.

You will also need to take into consideration the type of image you are loading as well.  While `ImageIO` has a larger support for image formats, loading animated GIFs is problematic and requires significant more work on you part to achieve.

ps - Don't load images in you component `paint` methods - paint can be called numerous times and loading images (or other resources) will dramatically slow the repaint process, making your application lag...

Comment: +1 Well Swing do implement ImageObservers, what if I use the old AWT classes.

Comment: `Where image resource is either a file or local URL`  I would not say `local URL`.  A sand-boxed applet or JWS app. can 'phone home for resources', while a trusted or no security manager app. can get an image from any URL what will supply the data & is not blocked by local settings.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I was thinking more along the lines of an embedded resource

Comment: That is also possible.  URLs are very versatile.  :)

Comment: @extremecoders java.awt.Componet implements ImageObserver, so your fine

Comment: @David we should always be questioned, even we need to clarify so e of our comments

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ImageIO.read()` for loading the images. This will block until the image is fully loaded. Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) page.

Comment: +1 The code you suggested works well. Anyways I was not using an animated gif.